# Get ID with upsert

Tags: custom-object, database, upsert, id

I'm trying to insert/update a custom object in database with `upsert` but after the `upsert` I need to get the database ID.

Is there a way to get the new/updated ID on database without querying the database ?

I tried something like this without success :

```
Id id = upsert(myCustomObject);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Salesforce sets these IDs back to list that is being upserts.

For example

> Upsert xxx;

now after this line you can put a loop to display ids like below -

```
for(TypeXXX afterUpsert : xxx){
   system.debug('*** Id = ' + afterUpsert.id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need. For my example, I only need to do this after the `upsert` : `Id id = myCustomObject.id;`

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer is the easiest solution, another way is to use Database.upsert(List) call.  From there, you can iterate through the array of Database.UpsertResult's returned.  More info here: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_upsert_2

Here's a small example of the Database.upsert call:

```
Set<Id> myIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Database.UpsertResult ur : Database.upsert(myRecords,false)){
    if(ur.isSuccess()){
        myIds.add(ur.getId());
    }
}
```